# What does a dot mean in matrix element index?

Tags: matrices, notation, index-notation

Seen here https://stat.ethz.ch/education/semesters/ss2012/ams/slides/v4.1.pdf (14th slide), the formula to compute b<sub>ij</sub>, we have, for instance, the elements d<sub>i.</sub> (notice the dot in place of j) and d<sub>..</sub> with two dots in place of ij. What do those dots mean?

Comment: @Yanko Are you sure? Then how does one compute $b_{ij} = d_{ij}^2 - d_{i\bullet}^2 - d_{\bullet j}^2 + d_{\bullet\bullet}^2$ . From that rationale, I interpret that as a summation of a scalar, two vectors and a matrix, right?

Comment: You are right, Yanko is wrong: in this instance $d_{i\cdot}$ means the average of the elements in row $i$ of the $d$ matrix.  Similarly $d_{\cdot j}$ and $d_{\cdot\cdot}$ are the averages of the elements in column $j$ and of all the elements in the matrix.

Comment: @kimchilover I think you should post it as an answer: http://polisci.msu.edu/jacoby/research/scaling/intromds/Jacoby-Ciuk,%20MDS,%20V2,%2010-29-14.pdf (see page 6) is exactly what you said.